# cuda how to calculate speedup

Tags: performance, cuda

hy, 
i have a xeon 4core with a gpu tesla c2050 [specific](http://www.nvidia.it/object/product_tesla_C2050_C2070_it.html)

i'm using a CUDA kernel and a serial cpu code. With cpu_code the time processing is 40s. With CUDA_kernel the same problem is processed in 2s.

I want to calculate the speed-up [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speedup):

CPU: s(4core)=40/2
CUDA: s(448core)=40/2  ?????

i'm confused, can you help me?

Answer (score 3):

The Wikipedia article makes it seem like "speedup" is some kind of scientific term with a specific definition. That is not the case :)

Simply calculate the ratio between the two implementations by dividing the time of the CPU implementation (40s) by the time of the GPU implementation (2s), and give the number with an "x" behind it, for "times". In your case, 40/2 = 20x.

Then, together with that number, provide details about the hardware, such as type and clock frequency of CPU and GPU, and implementations details such as the number of cores utilized by the CPU version.

Comment: Well, we do use the term "speedup" with a specific definition in scientific papers on parallel processing, but that specific definition is pretty much the one you gave: execution time of the fastest sequential algorithm divided by execution time of the parallel algorithm in question.

Comment: I find the wikipedia article quite right. Speedup is not scientific but this scientific definitions can give a better idea on what are the upper or lower bounds for an algorithm. The first formula given is actually the one given by @RogerDahl. You should check also Amdahl's and Gustafson's laws to have a comparison between speedup vs number-of-processors and/or speedup vs size-of-problem.